# GUI Authentication Requiring a Different User Auth

Tags: gnome, authentication, gksu

A few weeks ago a colleague signed into my Fedora 22 workstation. He too is a group admin. Ever since then whenever I attempt to install or unlock the "Authentication Required" modal requires his password and not mine.

[image]

How can I fix this? It's highly annoying.

One thing I need to point out is that my workstation uses winbind for LDAP authentication. I'd love to switch to sssd, but I just haven't had time to rebuild my profile.

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using?  Does the problem persist if you reboot?

Comment: I'm using Gnome and yes it still persists after reboot.